# Layout for survey

Tags: forms, gui-design, scrolling, surveys, wpf

I'm developing survey in wpf. First the user will input some info about them, then they should see the actual survey with following info:

1. The user info (they just filled)
2. List of questions and possible answers - scrollable (possibly dozens of them)
3. List of questions and selected answers - hopefully static (this should be visible at all times
4. Some form controls (contact support, confirm / cancel) etc.

Also user can get back to the same survey a week later, but some answers cannot be changed anymore and other can be edited to new value.

Now I thought the layout could be something like:

```
----------------------------------------
                         Form control 1

  Info panel
                         Form control 2
----------------------------------------
  ActionWindow            | DisplayWindow
                          | 
  Scrollable              | static list   
  list of questions       | of questions
  and possible answers    | and selected
                          | answer
                          |
                          |
                          |
                          |
                          |
                          |
----------------------------------------
             Confirm button
----------------------------------------
```

My problem is that with a big number of questions I can't possible show them all without some scrolling as well.

Any idea? Or better layout?

Edit: as requested

1. What's the purpose of this survey?

Bug reporting checklist. User will fill options in premade survey and technical support will make decision based on this input

2. Who are going to be using this system? The public, a small group?

Small group

3. Where shall they be using this system? Mobile, desktop, both?

Desktop with possibly small monitors (14 inch)

4. Why do the users need to see that scrollable list of questions and possible answers? How does that benefit the users?

The users are just filling the premade survey. They should see which options they selected or which options they selected last time the same issue was encountered.

Answer (score 1):

I think the layout you have is quite clear. I would **put the action window on the right**: as it will be scrollable either a page scrollbar or a div scrollbar will appear on the right, so better to be next to the list and on the right of the page.

I'm not sure about the confirm button being visible all the time (if I understood it correctly). If the confirmation is basically "save and come back later to continue" it is handy that way. If the confirmation will check that there are no empty questions, then better to display it after all the questions have been seen (in the lowest part of the action window).

Answer (score 0):

Well, to be honest, I think your user interface is a bit to complex. In order to make it easy for the user, use as few components on the screen as possible.

With that said, there is a lot of things yet to be answered in order to be able to provide you with a useful answer:

1. **What's** the purpose of this survey?
2. **Who** are going to be using this system? The public, a small group?
3. **Where** shall they be using this system? Mobile, desktop, both?
4. **Why** do the users need to se that scrollable list of questions and possible answers? How do that benefit the users?

If you update your question above, i will update my answer as well. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You are describing the situation with a lot of details, but I understand that basically, your **problem** is that you think you need to **display all the question without scroll**.

In a website, a regular page, it is true, not all the users scroll or some may read only the info above the fold and the attention is focused at the top. In a survey, where the users know the should answer all the questions, it is less important that the user must scroll once.

In my opinion, scrolling is ok in a survey, this not influences the decisions. It would be something else if the scroll is for the choices of one question or something like this.